# Can I use the Jenkins cloudbees deployer plugin for any type of app

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I would like to use the CloudBees deployer plugin (deploy to CloudBees) for Jenkins - is it limited to war files and web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Note if you use a ClickStart for the appropriate runtime container - then it will automatically set all this up for you, but if you aren't using one:

You can deploy any sort of app this way - the trick is to have the application set up to know what type it is.

So if you want to deploy a play2 app, you can run

```
bees app:update containerType=play2
```

Just once - it will remember it for all subsequent deploys (you can also use app:create to set this parameter via -t).

When you generate your build artefact, you should ensure it is a .zip file - so it isn't confused with a war file - but otherwise it works just the same.